python setup.py when i get setuptools but error
An error occurs after running python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
error code like this:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pkg_resources\\tests\\data\\my-test-package_unpacked-egg\\my_test_package-1.0-py3.7.egg\\EGG-INFO\\dependency_links.txt'

i did pip install setuptools
and i did python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel in setup.py directory
here i got an error like this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
After Googling, I found that using this command solved the problem.
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
but it is not working with error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pkg_resources\\tests\\data\\my-test-package_unpacked-egg\\my_test_package-1.0-py3.7.egg\\EGG-INFO\\dependency_links.txt'

i don't use dependency_links in setup.py
what's the problem?

It looks like you installed as admin, but are likely no running the script as admin (note the Administrator in the install path). Put a virtual environment in a place where all users can access it. Alternatively, if you need to use a global environment (in most cases I would not recommend it), install Python and the package for all users.

I have similar problem when I tried to create my virtual env.
What I did to resolve the problem is simply uninstall virturalenv and re-install the latest version.
Before uninstall, my computer is running virtualenv 20.17.1
After re-install, it is upgrade to virtualenv 20.26.6
Hope it helps.
